# Write generic static method in enum base class that can extract subclass instance to do a Jackson conversion

Tags: java, generics, jackson

I have some enum types that look like this:

```
public static enum Thingie {
    ABC("abc"), DEF("def");
    
    private String  messageValue;
    
    @JsonValue
    public String getMessageValue() { return messageValue; }
    
    private Thingie(String messageValue) { this.messageValue = messageValue; }
}
```

This will allow Jackson to properly marshal and unmarshal between string values and the enum type.

There may be times when I'd like to directly convert a string value to the enum value.  This would be like the internal "fromValue()" method, but not quite the same:

```
public static Thingie messageValueOf(String messageValue) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.convertValue(messageValue, Thingie.class);
}
```

I would like to convert this into a generic method AND put it into a base class, along with the "messageValue" property and accessor.  The constructor would change to just call "super(messageValue)".  Obviously, if I could do that, I would move the "mapper" to class level.

At this point, I've only attempted to write this as a generic method in the single enum type.  I can't even get that working.  I can't figure out how to extract the class from the template parameter.  I've seen this particular question before, and there have been some answers, but I couldn't quite get it to work, and I imagine trying to do this in the base class would add additional complexity.

Comment: Can you show your attempts at a generic method?

Comment: (deleted comments that were meant for an entirely different question - oof)

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume I understood your problem (correct me if I am wrong).

> The constructor would change to just call "super(messageValue)"

An enum can not extend a class, so you can't do that. But you can create an interface/class which you will delegate to for such queries (very simplistic code):

```
interface Test {

    ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    static <T extends Enum<T>> T getIt(String s, Class<T> clazz) {
        return MAPPER.convertValue(s, clazz);
    }

}


public static void main(String[] args)  {
    Thingie abc = Test.getIt("abc", Thingie.class);
    System.out.println(abc.ordinal());
}
```